# How to prove this light reflection problem in right triangle

Tags: geometry, analysis

The problem is from physics class，our teacher said that cavities with a small hole can approximate the blackbody.So I consider light reflection in the right triangle: In Rt Δ ABC, ∠ACB=π/2，∠A=θ(θ=nπ/2),n∈(0,1). The direction of a beam of light from point C and side AC form an Angle θ, when the light reaches the side of the triangle will reflect,reaches the vertex the light while leave the triangle.I found that when n is 1/2,1/3,1/4,1/5,2/5……,the light would return back on the same way and leave the triangle from point C.So when n is any rational number in (0,1),can the light return back on the same way and leave the triangle from point C?[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

use reflection of the triangle instead
of the reflection of the ray:

[image]